# Was the effect of gravity completely anticipated by the first to ascend in balloons and later airplanes?

Tags: gravity

I understand why the effects of gravity are felt in both balloons and high-flying planes and I believe that while it could have been calculated using Newton's law of gravitation, was there speculation by real scientists about what an observer would experience before such high flights occurred.

Comment: Given Newton's Laws were used to calculate the orbits of planets, amongst other things, it would be very strange if there weren't such speculation, and that answers calculated were treated as rather more certain than mere speculation.